# WSO2 Identity Server-5.10 : Verification for an Updated Mobile Number Not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have installed wso2 identity server '5.10' and I am trying to enable mobile number verification for an updated mobile number as desribed in the link below :

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/enable-mobile-verification-for-an-updated-mobile-number/#step-01-configuring-mobile-claim-verification-on-update

I have followed all the instructions detailled in the documentation but unfortunately , it is not working .

- In the management console , the feature is not displayed under : Main > Identity Providers > Resident > Account Management Policies > User Claim Update.
- When I try updating the mobile number via a PATCH operation to SCIM 2.0 Users endpoint, I get a json response but without the "pendingMobileNumber" element , as shown in the documentation .

Is there any other requirements needed in order for this feature to work ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this feature is available in the open-source product-is since IS-5.11.0.

Feature introducing issue: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/9045 delivered in 5.11.0-Beta5 version.

If you want to try out the flow in IS-5.10.0:

1. Need to patch the changes in the attached pull requests to your IS manualy or
2. If you have WSO2 support account you can get the WUM/U2 updated version of IS

The [documentation added in IS-5.10.0](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/enable-mobile-verification-for-an-updated-mobile-number/#step-01-configuring-mobile-claim-verification-on-update) should have mentioned that it will be availale after a specifc update version. WSO2 team will fix this documentation. Sorry for the inconvinence caused.